# Can't create database migration MYSQL and .NET CORE 3

Tags: mysql, .net-core

in visual studio i'm creating a migration using package manager console

The Nuget Packages i used:

- MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore 8.0.17
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore  3.0.0.0

Error encountered:

Method 'get_Info' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infraestructure.MySQLOptionsExtension' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.17.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.

Kindly help, thanks

Comment: It is better to use Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql instead of MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore. Oracle is taking months to fix bugs. Don't use it.

Comment: great thanks @pavinan,

Comment: Support for .NET Core 3.0 was added in [MySQL Connector/NET 8.0.18](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-net/en/news-8-0-18.html)